# IBM Mobilefirst server configuration tool without GUI

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I'm trying to install IBM Mobilefirst 7.0 server on production Ubuntu server in Amazon. The server has no GUI. I installed Websphere Application Server and IBM Mobilefirst server using silent installation of IBM Installation Manager and response file created on server with GUI. But now I'm stuck at a point where I have to configure MobileFirst server using server configuration tool. But I'm not able to find out how to do this without GUI since server configuration tool is GUI based. Any pointers or help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use ant tasks to proceed with the configuration without the GUI.

Detailed steps for this can be found in the link below.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/t_transporting_apps_and_adapters.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: It is not possible to write the entire set of commands mentioned in the documentation here, so it would be best to refer the link and follow the steps one by one. 
Below is the link to the main user documentation, it can be used if ever the link provided in my ans becomes invalid. 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNJXP/welcome.html

To summarize again - in an environment which doesn't have GUI support, there are Ant task scripts to proceed with the MFP configuration. 
Based on the Application server and the database used the particular ant configuration file can be made use of.

Answer (score 0):

What I was asking for is way to implement MobileFirst Server administration without using GUI as given in step number 6 in this link: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSHSCD_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/t_ov_server_install.html. Since the server I was working on does not have a GUI, I was stuck at step 6. But I found the way out now and for someone who is looking for this, the way to do is using ant scripts. Steps are listed at this link : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/devref/t_ant_tasks_configure_dbs_wlconsole.html